# How to combine float representation with discontinous function?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I have read tons of things about floating error, and floating approximation, and all that.
The thing is : I never read an answer to a real world problem. And today, I came across a real world problem. And this is really bad, and I really don't know how to escape.

Take a look at this example :

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        float t1 = 8460.32F;
        float t2 = 5990;
        var x = t1 - t2;
        var y = F(x);

        Assert.AreEqual(x, y);
    }

    float F(float x)
    {
        if (x <= 2470.32F) { return x; }
        else { return -x; }
    }
```

`x` is supposed to be `2470.32`. But in fact, due to rounding error, its value is `2470.32031`.
Most of the time, this is not a problem. Functions are continuous, and all is good, the result is off by a little value.
But here, we have a discontinous function, and the error is really, really big. The test failed exactly on the discontinuous point.

How could I handle the rounding error with discontinuous functions?

Comment: So what's the problem? I can think of four potential problems: first, that the constant 8460.32 will be converted to a float that does not have that exact value, because that exact value is not representable as a float. Second, that the same is true of 2470.32. Third, that the subtraction of two floats can induce yet another error, and fourth, that the code that does comparison of magnitudes may be incorrect.  Which of the four problems, if any, is your actual problem?

Comment: The answers to this question may or may not be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420009/avoid-rounding-error-floating-specifically-c

Comment: @EricLippert The subtraction of a float around 5990 from a float around 8460 is always exact (“Sterbenz lemma”), but with different constants, there could be an error induced by the subtraction.

Comment: Don't use a discontinuous function?  Take some small region at the threshold, and linearly interpolate between the two behaviors?  That won't make the test for floating-point equality pass, but it will yield minimal error.

Comment: I don't think there is any one-size-fits-all solution for the problem of discontinuous functions and practical, bounded precision, number representations. Can you give a bit more background on the reason for the discontinuous function, and the context in which it is being evaluated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key problem here is:

- The function has a large (and significant) change in output value in certain cases when there is a small change in input value.
- You are passing an incorrect input value to the function.

As you write, “due to rounding error, [x’s value] is 2470.32031”. Suppose you could write any code you desire—simply describe the function to be performed, and a team of expert programmers will provide complete, bug-free source code within seconds. What would you tell them?

The problem you are posing is, “I am going to pass a wrong value, 2470.32031, to this function. I want it to know that the correct value is something else and to provide the result for the correct value, which I did not pass, instead of the incorrect value, which I did pass.”

In general, that problem is impossible to solve, because it is impossible to distinguish when 2470.32031 is passed to the function but 2470.32 is intended from when 2470.32031 is passed to the function and 2470.32031 is intended. You cannot expect a computer to read your mind. When you pass incorrect input, you cannot expect correct output.

What this tells us is that **no solution inside of the function F is possible**. Therefore, we must zoom out and look at the larger problem. You must examine whether the value passed to F can be improved (calculated in a better way or with higher precision or with supplementary information) or whether the nature of the problem is such that, when 2470.32031 is passed, 2470.32 is always intended, so that this knowledge can be incorporated into F.

Comment: I like "a team of expert programmers will provide complete, bug-free source code within seconds." :)

Comment: Tanks you for putting the finger on what matters. I resolve the problem by adjusting the comportement of the function that call F. Not a very nice solution, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: this answer is essentially the same as the one of Eric
It just enlighten the test point of view, since a test is a form of specification.

The problem here is that testMethod1 does not test F.
It rather tests that conversion of decimal quantity 8460.32 to float and float subtraction are inexact.
But is it the intention of the test?
All you can say is that in certain bad conditions (near discontinuity), a small error on input will result in a large error on output, so the test could express that it is an expected result.

Note that function F is almost perfect, except maybe for the float value 2470.32F itself.
Indeed, the floating point approximation will round the decimal by excess (1/3200 exactly).
So the answer should be:

```
Assert.AreEqual(F(2470.32F), -2470.32F); /* because 2470.32F exceed the decimal 2470.32 */
```

If you want to test such low level requirements, you'll need a library with high (arbitrary/infinite) precision to perform the tests.

If you can't afford such imprecision on function F, then Float is a mismatch., and you'll have to find another implementation with increased, arbitrary or infinite precision.
It's up to you to specify your needs, and testMethod1 shall explicit this specification better than it does right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the 8460.32 number to be exactly that without rounding error, you could look at the .NET [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) type which was created explicitly to represent base 10 fractional numbers without rounding error. How they perform that magic is beyond me.

Now, I realize this may be impractical for you to do because the float presumably comes from somewhere and refactoring it to Decimal type could be way too much to do, but if you need it to have that much precision for the discontinuous function that relies on that value you'll either need a more precise type or some mathematical trickery. Perhaps there is some way to always ensure that a float is created that has rounding error such that it's always less than the actual number? I'm not sure if such a thing exists but it should also solve your issue.

Comment: The magic is simple; a decimal is a 96 bit unsigned integer, a sign bit, and an integer between 0 and 28 that indicates where the decimal point goes.  So 1.234 would be the 96 bit integer 1234, sign bit positive, decimal place 3. (Decimal place is measured from the right.)

Answer (score 1):

You have three numbers represented in your application, you have accepted imprecision in each of them by representing them as floats.

So I think you can reasonably claim that your program is working correctly

```
(oneNumber +/- some imprecision ) - (another number +/- some imprecision) 
        is not quite bigger than another number +/- some imprecision
```

when viewed in decimal representation on paper it looks wrong but that's not what you've implemented. What's the origin of the data? How precisely was 8460.32 known? Had it been 8460.31999 what should have happened? 8460.32001? Was the original value known to such precision?

In the end if you want to model more accuracy use a different data type, as suggested elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I always just assume that when comparing floating point values a small margin of error is needed because of rounding issues.  In your case, this would most likely mean choosing values in your test method that aren't quite so stringent--e.g., define a very small error constant and subtract that value from x.  Here's a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787125/evaluate-if-two-doubles-are-equal-based-on-a-given-precision-not-within-a-certa) that relates to this.

Edit to better address the concluding question: Presumably it doesn't matter what the function outputs on the discontinuity *exactly*, so test just slightly on either side of it.  If it does matter, then really about the best you can do is allow either of two outputs from the function at that point.